# Compare forecast from different dates

Tags: forecast

I want to compare forecast from two different dates e.g. I want to compare today's forecast and tomorrow's forecast and see if the forecast category has changed for any of the records and highlight it. I want to do it on a daily basis so want to automate it. Is it possible and if so then how?

Thanks,
DS